# Do I need to install SSRS on the SQL instance and the DBR or just the DBR?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint, reporting-services, cluster-computing

So here is the scenario...

I have the following servers

1. WFE
2. SP Application Server
3. DBR (where I want to run our reports, SQL reporting services already installed)
4. SQL (instance on a clustered environment) 2008 R2

SharePoint is installed with the SSRS add-in on machines 1-3 and I'm trying to install and configure reporting services on Machine 3. When I try to connect to the Reporting DB that our DBA created I find that I cannot hit the SQL node cluster (xyzSQLbox\instanceNode).

In short do I need to install reporting services on Machine 4 to access it with SSRS on Machine 3, or am I missing some step? Also, is this configuration even possible?

Help me stack overflow your my only hope!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "DBR"? Is this a server with only the Reporting Services service installed? What is the on the SQL instance, the data sources for your reports or the Report Server databases?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to install SSRS on your SQL backend.  If you cannot connect to SQL that probably points to a firewall or security issue.